# Dynamic Layout setLayoutParams Not Being Set

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a routine that creates `TableRow`s dynamically inside a `TableLayout` that is inflated from XML. I am trying to set the `TableRow`s to be a specific width, filling them with a custom button (`ButtonElement`)... but nothing is showing up. Logging out the `TableRow` width, and it seems that it is set to 0, which might explain why it is not being displayed.

```
final Drawable normalBtnBg = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_states);
TableRow tableRow;
for (int x = 0; x < xDim; x++) {
    tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(400, 20));
    for (int y = 0; y < yDim; y++) {
        // create the new button
        mButtons[x][y] = new ButtonElement(this, x, y);
        mButtons[x][y].setBackgroundDrawable(normalBtnBg);
        mButtons[x][y].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(20, 20));

        // add the button to the TableLayout
        tableRow.addView(mButtons[x][y]);
    }

    // add the TableRow to the table
    mButtonGrid.addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(400, 20));
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "trWidth - " + tableRow.getWidth());
}
```

`tableRow.getWidth()` always returns a value of 0... I have verified the buttons are being generated, as if I add them directly to the `mButtonGrid`, they are displayed (of course, not in a `TableRow`, just vertically down).

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

Figured this out, see my answer below.

Comment: Could you print the result from tabeRow.getMeasuredWidth() ?

Comment: @Damian - the value is also 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, solved this issue... I was using TableLayout.LayoutParams, but needed to use the TableRow.LayoutParams to make it work (from [here](http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/Dynamically_adding_rows_to_TableLayout)):

```
final Drawable normalBtnBg = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_states);
TableRow tableRow;
for (int x = 0; x < xDim; x++) {
    tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(400, 20));
    for (int y = 0; y < yDim; y++) {
        // create the new button
        mButtons[x][y] = new ButtonElement(this, x, y);
        mButtons[x][y].setBackgroundDrawable(normalBtnBg);
        mButtons[x][y].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(20, 20));

        // add the button to the TableLayout
        tableRow.addView(mButtons[x][y]);
    }

    // add the TableRow to the table
    mButtonGrid.addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(400, 20));
}
```